# Automate concatenation process

Tags: excel, vba

Here I am stucked with one excel issue where i want to concatenate from column F till column I where the logic is when the benchmark column A3 (for example) is blank it need to concatenate column F till column I till there is a value at column A4.and this logic need to automatically concatenate the mentioned column till there is a value under the benchmark column. currently i need to keep change the concatenate range in order to concatenate it fully with the logic. Appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Below image shows how i am doing manually which very time consuming

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the INDIRECT function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MATCH` function (with a wildcard) to find the next non-blank row; and use that in an `INDEX` function to detect the range to concatenate.

Assuming your data starts in A3 and the lowest possible row is row 1000 (change the `1000`'s in the formula below if it might be much different:

```
J2: =IF(A2="","",CONCAT(INDEX(F2:$I$1000,1,0):INDEX(F2:$I$1000,IFERROR(MATCH("*",A3:$A$1000,0),1000-ROW()),0)))
```

[image]

*Note:  It is possible to also develop solutions using `INDIRECT` and/or `OFFSET`. Unfortunately, these functions are volatile, which means they recalculate anytime anything changes on your worksheet. If there are a number of formulas using these functions, worksheet performance will be impaired. `INDEX` and `MATCH` are non-volatile (except in ancient versions of Excel - pre-2003 or so)*

Comment: Very helpful explanations with interesting hint to performance :-)

Answer (score 0):

The OFFSET-function would come on handy here. One solution is to do it like

[image: this]

This works in my worksheet.

Cell Q6 just defines the number of rows downwards that the MATCH-function is checking for the next "HEADER1" value. If "HEADER1" is found, the MATCH-function returns how many rows down-1. If no "HEADER1"-value is found within that range, that value is then the number of rows used.

If the first column also has "HEADER2" and so on, you can add the MID-function to both references inside MATCH to limit which part of the string are to be searched for.

I tried to adjust the references properly to fit your sheet, but I may have missed something:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($B2),"",CONCAT(OFFSET($B2,0,0,IFNA(MATCH(MID($B2,1,6),MID(OFFSET($B2,1,0,$B$1),1,6),0),$B$1),4)))
```